# Get execution time of running PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, execution-time

I'm running a query out of pgAdmin 4 against a Postgres 9.5 database. Is there any method to get an estimation on how long this query will run? It is running now for nearly 20 hours.

I only found info about logging and similar to get the actual execution time after the query finished.

The query is about to order about 300,000 postGIS points using `st_distance` in a recursive CTE.

Has SQL or Postgres any mechanism to prevent infinite running queries? The recursion should stop at some point, is there maybe a way to peek at the last constructed row, which would give me a hint, how far the query is in the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If your transaction is in a dead lock, PostgreSQL may solve it by killing one (or some) of the transaction(s) involved.

Else, you have to master what you're doing.

When you use `EXPLAIN` (without `ANALYZE`), the planner is estimating your query duration but this value has to be taken as relative not absolute.